# Adding new rows to Tkinter app

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to add new rows to simple table app (Thanks to @Bryan Oakley) that takes inputs from the table fields and stores it. I added button "addrow" and that is defined to to add +1 rows to the SimpleTableInput:

```
self.addrow = tk.Button(self,text="Add row", command=self.addrow)
self.addrow.pack()

def addrow(self):
    self.table.append([])
```

But this solution fails.

```
AttributeError: SimpleTableInput instance has no attribute 'append'
```

Ideally it would update the new row graphics to new row of data.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SimpleTableInput(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self._entry = {}
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns

        # register a command to use for validation
        vcmd = (self.register(self._validate), "%P")

        # create the table of widgets
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for column in range(self.columns):
                index = (row, column)
                e = tk.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
                e.grid(row=row, column=column, stick="nsew")
                self._entry[index] = e
        # adjust column weights so they all expand equally
        for column in range(self.columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
        # designate a final, empty row to fill up any extra space
        self.grid_rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)

    def get(self):
        '''Return a list of lists, containing the data in the table'''
        result = []
        for row in range(self.rows):
            current_row = []
            for column in range(self.columns):
                index = (row, column)
                current_row.append(self._entry[index].get())
            result.append(current_row)
        return result

    def _validate(self, P):
        '''Perform input validation. 

        Allow only an empty value, or a value that can be converted to a float
        '''
        if P.strip() == "":
            return True

        try:
            f = float(P)
        except ValueError:
            self.bell()
            return False
        return True



class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.table = SimpleTableInput(self, 2, 2)
        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.on_submit)
        self.table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="bottom")

        self.addrow = tk.Button(self,text="Add row", command=self.addrow)
        self.addrow.pack()

    def on_submit(self):
        print(self.table.get())

    def addrow(self):
        self.table.append([])




root = tk.Tk()
Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's it doing/What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `self.table.append`, you have to write an `append` method for `SimpleTableInput`. That could be something like:

```
def append(self):
    row = self.rows
    for column in range(self.columns):
        index = (row, column)
        e = tk.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=self.vcmd)
        e.grid(row=row, column=column, stick="nsew")
        self._entry[index] = e
    self.rows += 1
```

Which checks how many rows there are and places one more underneath it in the same way as you make the rows in the `__init__` method.
To use this you have to rename `vcmd` to `self.vcmd` in `__init__`, and you can all it using:

```
def addrow(self):
    self.table.append()
```

---

You can indeed use a similar approach to delete the last row (I'm on my tablet right now so I haven't tested this but I think it should work):

```
def delete(self):
    row = self.rows - 1
    for column in range(self.columns):
        index = (row, column)
        self._entry[index].grid_remove()
    self.rows -= 1
```

Just create a new button in your `Example` class that calls `self.table.delete()`

Comment: could deleting rows be done with the same tactic? Or with del []

Comment: Yeah thank you so much @fhdrsdg ! Works perfectly! But why do you need to use row= self.rows -1. The minus one at the end confuses me. I tried to delete with only self.rows -= 1 but that didn't work.

Comment: Because indexing in python starts with 0. If you have 4 rows, they will be row 0, 1, 2 and 3. So the last row is the nummer of rows minus 1.

Comment: Of course @fhdrsdg ! Makes perfect sense now that you say that.. :)

Comment: May I ask where did you learn to use Tkinter? Can you recommend a book?

Comment: I didn't use a book. I got most of my information from [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/), [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm), [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) and other questions here on SO